# Geektool not working with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, geektool

When I try to run a python script with python3 it does not work but it works when I just use python. Why is this?

I have a simple hello.py file:

```
__author__ = 'A'
print("hellow")
```

When I use python ~/path/hello.py with geektool it works, but not with python3 ~/path/hello.py, the same works from terminal.

Also, where can I see geektool's log file?

Comment: What do you get if you type `type python3` in Terminal?

Comment: I get 
    Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 00:54:21)

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I don't know where I can check errors with geektool. Is there a log file somewhere?

Comment: I'd understand if `python3` spit out `Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1...)`, but `type python3` should spit out something like `python3 is /usr/bin/python3` or ``python3 is aliased to `python3.4'``. Are you sure you typed `type python3` rather than `python3`?

Comment: The problem's only with geektool. Both python3 and python workfine from terminal.

Comment: I get this when I say `type python3` : python3 is hashed (/usr/local/bin/python3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments, it looks like you have Python 3 installed at `/usr/local/bin/python3`. It could be that that's not part of the default `PATH`, but you've configured your login shell to add it to the `PATH`. Since your other program either executes the program directly or does it through a non-login shell, it won't read that configuration, and the `PATH` will remain at its default, excluding that directory. If that's the case, you might have to instead change your command to have an absolute path to Python:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 /path/to/hello.py
```

This should work from the Terminal and any other environments.